# remove object out from pool in apache common pool2

Tags: threadpool, apache-commons, pool, object-pooling

I have created `GenericPool` by extending `GenericObjectPool` and `poolFactory` using `BasePooledObjectFactory`. Now I want to remove the object from my Generic Pool.

`.clear()` will remove `idleObject` from pool how do we remove permanently from the pool?

Answer (score 1):

Your poolFactory must implement the method

```
void destroyObject(PooledObject<T> p) throws Exception;
```

While your code should be calling method

```
public void invalidateObject(final T obj) throws Exception
```

on the GenericPool

At runtime, if you run into an exception situation (perhaps caused by a temp network issue) you need to remove the object from the pool and re-create it, so calling invalidateObject will destroy this object and automatically create new one when you call borrowObject